# fastest way to make multiple dataframes from a small dataset

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I need to make *n* tables from a small dataset(145k lines) made from a query, and the ways I've tried were using `collect()` and `cache()`, but `collect()` ended up way faster than `cache()`
(5 seconds against 30 seconds....)

Examples I'm using.
collect():

```
df = spark.sql(query).collect()
list_a = [Row(col1=i['col1']) for i in df if i['col2'] == 'test']
list_b = [Row(col1=i['col1']) for i in df if i['col2'] == 'derp']
```

cache():

```
df=spark.sql(query)
df.cache()
list_a = df.filter(df['col2'] == 'test').select('col1').collectAsList()
list_b = df.filter(df['col2'] == 'derp').select('col1').collectAsList()
```

Is there another way that is faster than `collect()`?
Is `collect()` better for small datasets or is not worth because something?

Comment: What do you mean by "table"? Do you want to read a dataset file using pyspark? Do you understand the purpose of `cache()`?

Comment: I mean dataframe. I need to make 4 different tables in a datalake storage from the same dataset, but I ended up using df.collect() instead df.cache() to make the tables because is faster. I know cache is when you need to use the same df more than once in the same session, but I don't get how serializing using collect() is faster than using cache() to proccess data with spark. I'm just wondering if there is another way that is better, or am I doing something wrong.

Comment: `cache()` is not meant for serialization, it might be just a side-effect. If you want to serialize a DataFrame, you can use `df.write` and choose one encoding type, like [CSV](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.3/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameWriter.csv).